# Most efficient way to determine overlapping timeseries in Python

Tags: python, performance, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I am trying to determine what percentage of the time that two time series overlap using python's pandas library. The data is nonsynchronous so the times for each data point do not line up. Here is an example:

**Time Series 1**

```
2016-10-05 11:50:02.000734    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:03.000033    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:10.000479    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:15.000234    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:37.000199    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:49.000401    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:51.000362    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:53.000424    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:53.000982    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:58.000606    0.75
```

**Time Series 2**

```
2016-10-05 11:50:07.000537    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:11.000994    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:19.000181    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:35.000578    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:46.000761    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:49.000295    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:51.000835    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:55.000792    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:55.000904    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:57.000444    0.75
```

Assuming the series holds its value until the next change what is the most efficient way to determine the percentage of time that they have the same value?

**Example**

Lets calculate the time that these series overlap starting at 11:50:07.000537 and ending at 2016-10-05 11:50:57.000444    0.75 since we have data for both series for that period. Time that there is overlap:

- 11:50:10.000479 - 11:50:15.000234 (both have a value of 0.5) **4.999755 seconds**
- 11:50:37.000199 - 11:50:49.000295 (both have a value of 0.5) **12.000096 seconds**
- 11:50:53.000424 - 11:50:53.000982 (both have a value of 0.75) **0.000558 seconds**
- 11:50:55.000792 - 11:50:55.000904 (both have a value of 0.25) **0.000112 seconds**

The result (4.999755+12.000096+0.000558+0.000112) / 49.999907 = **34%**

One of the issues is my actual timeseries has much more data such as 1000 - 10000 observations and I need to run many more pairs. I thought about forward filling a series and then simply comparing the rows and dividing the total number of matches over the total number of rows but I do not think this would be very efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***setup***
create 2 time series

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd


txt1 = """2016-10-05 11:50:02.000734    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:03.000033    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:10.000479    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:15.000234    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:37.000199    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:49.000401    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:51.000362    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:53.000424    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:53.000982    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:58.000606    0.75"""

s1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt1), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python',
                 parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, header=None,
                 squeeze=True).rename('s1').rename_axis(None)

txt2 = """2016-10-05 11:50:07.000537    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:11.000994    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:19.000181    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:35.000578    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:46.000761    0.50
2016-10-05 11:50:49.000295    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:51.000835    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:55.000792    0.25
2016-10-05 11:50:55.000904    0.75
2016-10-05 11:50:57.000444    0.75"""

s2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt2), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python',
                 parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, header=None,
                 squeeze=True).rename('s2').rename_axis(None)
```

---

***TL;DR***

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).ffill().dropna()
overlap = df.index.to_series().diff().shift(-1) \
            .fillna(0).groupby(df.s1.eq(df.s2)).sum()
overlap.div(overlap.sum())

False    0.666657
True     0.333343
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

---

***explanation***

***build base `pd.DataFrame` `df`***

- use `pd.concat` to align indexes
- use `ffill` to let values propagate forward
- use `dropna` to get rid of values of one series prior to the other starting

---

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).ffill().dropna()
df
```

[image]

***calculate `'duration'`***
from current time stamp to next

```
df['duration'] = df.index.to_series().diff().shift(-1).fillna(0)
df
```

[image]

***calculate overlap***

- `df.s1.eq(df.s2)` gives boolean series of when `s1` overlaps with `s2`
- use `groupby` above boolean series to aggregate total duration when `True` and `False`

---

```
overlap = df.groupby(df.s1.eq(df.s2)).duration.sum()
overlap

False   00:00:33.999548
True    00:00:17.000521
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

***percentage of time with same value***

```
overlap.div(overlap.sum())

False    0.666657
True     0.333343
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Neat! Cosmetic question: any rationale using .eq over == but coding style here?

Comment: @Boud coding style. I don't like wrapping the whole expression in parentheses if I want to do something else. I think I even tested it as faster under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Cool problem. I brute forced this w/out using pandas or numpy, but I got your answer (thanks for working it out). I have not tested it on anything else. I also don't know how fast it is since it only goes through each dataframe once, but does not do any vectorization.

```
import pandas as pd
#############################################################################
#Preparing the dataframes
times_1 = ["2016-10-05 11:50:02.000734","2016-10-05 11:50:03.000033",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:10.000479","2016-10-05 11:50:15.000234",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:37.000199","2016-10-05 11:50:49.000401",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:51.000362","2016-10-05 11:50:53.000424",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:53.000982","2016-10-05 11:50:58.000606"]
times_1 = [pd.Timestamp(t) for t in times_1]
vals_1 = [0.50,0.25,0.50,0.25,0.50,0.50,0.25,0.75,0.25,0.75]

times_2 = ["2016-10-05 11:50:07.000537","2016-10-05 11:50:11.000994",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:19.000181","2016-10-05 11:50:35.000578",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:46.000761","2016-10-05 11:50:49.000295",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:51.000835","2016-10-05 11:50:55.000792",
           "2016-10-05 11:50:55.000904","2016-10-05 11:50:57.000444"]
times_2 = [pd.Timestamp(t) for t in times_2]
vals_2 = [0.50,0.50,0.50,0.50,0.50,0.75,0.75,0.25,0.75,0.75]

data_1 = pd.DataFrame({"time":times_1,"vals":vals_1})
data_2 = pd.DataFrame({"time":times_2,"vals":vals_2})
#############################################################################

shared_time = 0      #Keep running tally of shared time
t1_ind = 0           #Pointer to row in data_1 dataframe
t2_ind = 0           #Pointer to row in data_2 dataframe

#Loop through both dataframes once, incrementing either the t1 or t2 index
#Stop one before the end of both since do +1 indexing in loop
while t1_ind < len(data_1.time)-1 and t2_ind < len(data_2.time)-1:
    #Get val1 and val2
    val1,val2 = data_1.vals[t1_ind], data_2.vals[t2_ind]

    #Get the start and stop of the current time window
    t1_start,t1_stop = data_1.time[t1_ind], data_1.time[t1_ind+1]
    t2_start,t2_stop = data_2.time[t2_ind], data_2.time[t2_ind+1]

    #If the start of time window 2 is in time window 1
    if val1 == val2 and (t1_start <= t2_start <= t1_stop):
        shared_time += (min(t1_stop,t2_stop)-t2_start).total_seconds()
        t1_ind += 1
    #If the start of time window 1 is in time window 2
    elif val1 == val2 and t2_start <= t1_start <= t2_stop:
        shared_time += (min(t1_stop,t2_stop)-t1_start).total_seconds()
        t2_ind += 1
    #If there is no time window overlap and time window 2 is larger
    elif t1_start < t2_start:
        t1_ind += 1
    #If there is no time window overlap and time window 1 is larger
    else:
        t2_ind += 1

#How I calculated the maximum possible shared time (not pretty)
shared_start = max(data_1.time[0],data_2.time[0])
shared_stop = min(data_1.time.iloc[-1],data_2.time.iloc[-1])
max_possible_shared = (shared_stop-shared_start).total_seconds()

#Print output
print "Shared time:",shared_time
print "Total possible shared:",max_possible_shared
print "Percent shared:",shared_time*100/max_possible_shared,"%"
```

Output:

```
Shared time: 17.000521
Total possible shared: 49.999907
Percent shared: 34.0011052421 %
```

Comment: cool, this is what I was looking for but I was hoping for some faster solution. I did need to change the logic under if val1 != val2: to the same index updating if there is a match because you cannot assume you just can move the first index

Comment: @klib yeah I also feel there is likely a pandas or numpy solution. You are definitely right about not being able to assume the first index, I've edited my answer